# Counting hyperplane arrangements up to combinatorial equivalence, simple examples and history

Tags: co.combinatorics, posets, enumerative-combinatorics, integer-sequences, hyperplane-arrangements

Two arrangements of (affine) hyperplanes in $d$-dimensional Euclidean space are combinatorially isomorphic (or combinatorially equivalent) if they have isomorphic posets of faces.

Counting the number $A(n,d)$ of equivalence classes of arrangements, given $n$ distinct hyperplanes in (affine) $\mathbb{R}^d,$ is definitely a hard problem. Note that the number of polytopes with $n$ facets is a subproblem. I'm just wondering whether some easy small cases of this have been worked out, either recently or historically.

Some related answers to this question are out there. For instance, http://oeis.org/A241600 counts the number of arrangements of lines in the affine plane. (Edit: Peter Shor points out below that this sequence is defined differently than via combinatorial equivalence.)  Some nice pictures are included at http://oeis.org/A241600/a241600.pdf This gives a start to the question in dimension 3. The four arrangements of three lines ($A(3,2) =4$) can be extended along the third dimension to get arrangements of 3 planes in 3 dimensions, and then of course there is a fifth in which the three planes intersect at a point. These five ($A(3,3) = 5$) are pictured in many beginner algebra texts.

Drawing similar pictures, I think that $A(4,3) \ge 14.$ That is, that there are at least fourteen combinatorial equivalence classes of affine hyperplane arrangements using four planes in $\mathbb{R}^3.$ What else is known?

Comment: Maybe related, this work on the number of matroids of a given rank on a ground set of a given cardinality: https://homepages.dias.ie/dukes/matroid.html

Comment: Thanks Zach! Surely there is a connection between the enumeration of some sets of matroids and this question. However it is unclear (at least to me) which matroids (or semimatroids) might be in bijection with real affine hyperplane arrangements. That might be an open question as well?

Comment: Let me add the link to the corresponding question on MES, where I focus on the case $A(4,3).$  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2878325/how-many-ways-can-four-planes-be-arranged-in-space

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but if you fix some (multi)set of linear hyperplanes and then look at all affine hyperplane arrangements obtained from this set by translating some hyperplanes along their normals, then this moduli space naturally has the structure of a hyperplanes arrangement, which is called (if I recall correctly) the “discriminantal arrangement” of your set of linear hyperplanes

Comment: A241600 does not count the number of arrangements that are equivalent according to your definition. It counts the number that are equivalent with the definition "Two arrangements are considered the same if one can be continuously changed to the other while keeping all lines straight, without changing the multiplicity of intersection points, and without a line passing through an intersection point. Turning over is also allowed." These two definitions are different for large enough $n$.

Comment: This presentation has a suggestive title: "Counting Hyperplane Arrangements," T. Paul, W. Traves, M. Wakefield. 2012. [PDF download](https://www.usna.edu/Users/math/traves/presentations/queens.pdf).

Comment: Thanks @PeterShor ! I will edit my original post with a note about your comment. I've been looking for an example that shows the definitions are different--if you know where one is I'd be interested.

Comment: @Stefan: Two such arrangements can be constructed from Section 3 of my paper ["Stretchability of pseudo-line arrangements is NP-hard",](http://math.mit.edu/~shor/papers/Stretchability_NP-hard.pdf) and are implicit in [Mnëv's universality theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mn%C3%ABv%27s_universality_theorem). Jurgen Richter-Gebert probably has the best exposition of this theorem somewhere.

Comment: I have no idea whether anybody has figured out the smallest pair of such pseudo-line arrangements. So it's quite possible that the sequence A241600 coincides with the sequence you're interested in up to $n=7$ (the highest term in the OEIS). I'm tempted to ask the question of whether anybody knows a small such pair on MathOverflow.

Comment: Here is a picture of 14 arrangements of 4 planes in ℝ^3. https://sforcey.github.io/sf34/four_planes.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combinatorial types of hyperplane arrangements are called dissection types in the dissertation of L. Finschi: https://finschi.com/math/publ/2001-08-31_Finschi_A-Graph-Theoretical-Approach-for-Reconstruction-and-Generation-of-Oriented-Matroids.pdf

This thesis is a great source for the connection between oriented matroids and the known answers to this question. For instance the first few terms in sequence of numbers of arrangements of $n$ 2D planes in 3 dimensions, up to combinatorial equivalence, can be found from Table 8.1 on page 165. Sum the first three rows to get the sequence 1, 2, 5, 14, 74, 1854, ...

[edit] Note however that this table (probably for higher $n$) counts pseudo-hyperplane arrangements, so the question is still open how many of each are realizable as hyperplane arrangements.